# Strange error using a class array for a thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-errors

I'm trying to do a `Thread` calling the cook class through a vector but I don't know to do it correctly. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _numCooks; i++) {
     std::thread threadObj(this->_cooks[i].nextOrder, void);
    _threads.push_back(threadObj);
}
```

_cooks is a vector of a class and the function that I am trying to make a thread of is:

```
bool cooks::nextOrder()
{
    Margarita margarita(_cookOrder[0].pizzaSize);
    Regina regina(_cookOrder[0].pizzaSize);
    Fantasia fantasia(_cookOrder[0].pizzaSize);
    Americana americana(_cookOrder[0].pizzaSize);
    if (_cookOrder.empty())
        return (false);
    switch (_cookOrder[0].pizzaType) {
        case plazza::Margarita:
            return (makeOrder(margarita));
            break;
        case plazza::Regina:
            return (makeOrder(regina));
            break;
        case plazza::Fantasia:
            return (makeOrder(fantasia));
            break;
        case plazza::Americana:
            return (makeOrder(americana));
            break;
        default:
            return (false);

    }
}
```

however when I try to compile I get this:

> kitchen/kitchen.cpp: In member function ‘void
>   Kitchen::make_pizza(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, Ipc)’:
>   kitchen/kitchen.cpp:148:59: error: expected primary-expression before
>   ‘void’
>             std::thread threadObj(this->_cooks[i].nextOrder, void);
>                                                              ^~~~ kitchen/kitchen.cpp:148:63: error: invalid use of non-static member
>   function ‘bool cooks::nextOrder()’
>             std::thread threadObj(this->_cooks[i].nextOrder, void);
>                                                                  ^ In file included from kitchen/kitchen.hpp:17,
>                    from kitchen/kitchen.cpp:5: kitchen/cooks.hpp:32:10: note: declared here
>        bool nextOrder();
>             ^~~~~~~~~ In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/allocator.h:46,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/8/string:41,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/8/ios:42,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/8/ostream:38,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:39,
>                    from kitchen/../pizza/IPizza.hpp:23,
>                    from kitchen/../pizza/APizza.hpp:11,
>                    from kitchen/kitchen.hpp:8,
>                    from kitchen/kitchen.cpp:5: /usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void
>   __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = cooks; _Args = {const cooks&}; _Tp = cooks]’: /usr/include/c++/8/bits/alloc_traits.h:475:4:   required from ‘static
>   void std::allocator_traits
>   ::construct(std::allocator_traits >::allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = cooks; _Args = {const cooks&}; _Tp = cooks;
>   std::allocator_traits >::allocator_type =
>   std::allocator]’ /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:1079:30: 
>   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const
>   value_type&) [with _Tp = cooks; _Alloc = std::allocator;
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = cooks]’
>   kitchen/kitchen.cpp:36:30:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: use of deleted
>   function ‘cooks::cooks(const cooks&)’   { ::new((void *)__p)
>   _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
>       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from kitchen/kitchen.hpp:17,
>                    from kitchen/kitchen.cpp:5: kitchen/cooks.hpp:21:7: note: ‘cooks::cooks(const cooks&)’ is implicitly deleted because the
>   default definition would be ill-formed:  class cooks
>          ^~~~~ kitchen/cooks.hpp:21:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const
>   std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits =
>   std::char_traits]’ In file included from
>   kitchen/../plazza.hpp:15,
>                    from kitchen/kitchen.hpp:13,
>                    from kitchen/kitchen.cpp:5: /usr/include/c++/8/fstream:778:7: note: declared here
>          basic_ofstream(const basic_ofstream&) = delete;
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/vector:62,
>                    from kitchen/../pizza/IPizza.hpp:24,
>                    from kitchen/../pizza/APizza.hpp:11,
>                    from kitchen/kitchen.hpp:8,
>                    from kitchen/kitchen.cpp:5: /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void
>   std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = cooks; _Args =
>   {cooks}]’: /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:
>   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator
>   std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator; _ForwardIterator = cooks*; bool
>   _TrivialValueTypes = false]’ /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from
>   ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator,
>   _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator; _ForwardIterator = cooks*]’
>   /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from
>   ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator,
>   _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator; _ForwardIterator = cooks*; _Tp = cooks]’
>   /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:311:2:   required from
>   ‘_ForwardIterator
>   std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator,
>   _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = cooks*; _ForwardIterator = cooks*; _Allocator =
>   std::allocator]’ /usr/include/c++/8/bits/vector.tcc:447:6:
>   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp,
>   _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const cooks&}; _Tp = cooks; _Alloc =
>   std::allocator; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = cooks*]’
>   /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:1085:4:   required from ‘void
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp =
>   cooks; _Alloc = std::allocator; std::vector<_Tp,
>   _Alloc>::value_type = cooks]’ kitchen/kitchen.cpp:36:30:   required from here /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of
>   deleted function ‘cooks::cooks(const cooks&)’
>        { ::new(static_cast(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   make: *** [: kitchen/kitchen.o] Error 1

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Some compilation errors are due to `cooks` being non-copyable.  Make sure you understand https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three and know whether `cooks` members are copyable or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), the first argument to a `std::thread` constructor should meet the *Callable* concept.  You then pass the subsequent arguments for the *Callable* as additional arguments to the constructor.

You're passing a member function.  You need an instance of the class to call the method on, which you're not providing.  This is what this error should mean to you.

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘bool cooks::nextOrder()’
```

It's probably easiest to use a lambda ie.

```
for (int i = 0; i < _numCooks; i++) {
    _threads.emplace_back([&cook = _cooks[i]]() {
        cook.nextOrder();
     });
}
```

Comment: Also, `std::thread`s are not copy constructible. It should be moved into _threads: `_threads.emplace_back(std::move(threadObj))`

Comment: hi after trying your answer i get this compilation error
kitchen/kitchen.o: In function `std::thread::thread<Kitchen::make_pizza(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Ipc)::{lambda()#1}, , void>(Kitchen::make_pizza(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Ipc)::{lambda()#1}&&)':
kitchen.cpp:(.text+0x27c7): undefined reference to `pthread_create'

Comment: @HectorTorrents you will need to link to `-lpthread` or similar